# Python Regular Expression Match All 5 Digit Numbers but None Larger

Tags: python, regex

I'm attempting to string match 5-digit coupon codes spread throughout a HTML web page. For example, `53232`, `21032`, `40021` etc... I can handle the simpler case of any string of 5 digits with `[0-9]{5}`, though this also matches 6, 7, 8... n digit numbers.  Can someone please suggest how I would modify this regular expression to match *only* 5 digit numbers?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> s="four digits 1234 five digits 56789 six digits 012345"
>>> re.findall(r"\D(\d{5})\D", s)
['56789']
```

if they can occur at the very beginning or the very end, it's easier to pad the string than mess with special cases

```
>>> re.findall(r"\D(\d{5})\D", " "+s+" ")
```

Comment: I highlighted difference between \D and \b in regex in my answer .

Comment: `re.findall(r"\D(\d{5})\D","15/05/2018 a8711 43160")` gives `[ ]`. What gives?

Comment: @Aetos. It says right there in the answer that you would need to pad this input string. Lookahead and look behind can greatly reduce the performance of your regex. I would be interested if you could report what you find.

Answer (score 22):

Without padding the string for special case start and end of string, as in [John La Rooy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/174728/john-la-rooy) answer one can use the negatives lookahead and lookbehind to handle both cases with a single regular expression

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "88888 999999 3333 aaa 12345 hfsjkq 98765"
>>> re.findall(r"(?<!\d)\d{5}(?!\d)", s)
['88888', '12345', '98765']
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, the one selected as the solution isn't

Answer (score 16):

full string: `^[0-9]{5}$`

within a string: `[^0-9][0-9]{5}[^0-9]`

Comment: thanks, actually, confused with solution '\b\d{5}\b' and '^[0-9]{5}$', thanks for point it out, the later one then create the expression as a string, that is what I need.

Comment: this answer don't work at the begining and of the string. For example it doesn't match "12345"

Comment: @Crayon Violent [^0-9][0-9]{5}[^0-9] --> Can you please explain this regex ?

Comment: @DhiwakarRavikumar  `[^0-9]` Any 1 character that is not a digit, followed by `[0-9]{5}` exactly 5 digits, followed by `[^0-9]` any 1 character that is not a digit

Answer (score 6):

**Note:** There is problem in using `\D` since `\D` matches any character that is not a digit , instead use `\b`.
`\b` is important  here because it matches the word boundary but only at end or beginning of a word .

```
import re  

input = "four digits 1234 five digits 56789 six digits 01234,56789,01234"


re.findall(r"\b\d{5}\b", input)  

result : ['56789', '01234', '56789', '01234']
```

but if one uses 
    re.findall(r"\D(\d{5})\D", s)
    output : ['56789', '01234']
\D is unable to handle comma or any continuously entered numerals.

\b is important part here it matches the empty string but only at end or beginning of a word .

More documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

**More Clarification on usage of `\D` vs `\b`**:

[This example](https://regex101.com/r/hmCsw4/1) uses `\D` but it doesn't capture all the five digits number.

[This example](https://regex101.com/r/DEI0fg/1) uses `\b` while capturing all five digits number.

Cheers

Comment: I changed your regex to use a raw string there since `\b` is otherwise a valid escape character in strings. The problem with this answer is that it doesn't work for if other alpha characters are joined to the string of digits eg. "56789a"

Comment: @gnibbler neither is \D able to handle it too !

Comment: You mean `\D` doesn't handle the beginning or end of strings? I dealt with that in my answer.

Comment: @gnibbler i mean it doesn't handle "56789a"

Comment: "56789a" is matched as "56789" using `\D`

Comment: as John said that answer fail to find 5 consecutives digits in "12345a"

Comment: @xavier-combelle I have added extra clarification. Also "12345a" isn't a 5 digit number, it's an alpha-numeric. The question specifically says 5 digits numbers with example.

Answer (score 3):

A very simple way would be to match all groups of digits, like with `r'\d+'`, and then skip every match that isn't five characters long when you process the results.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to match a non-digit before and after your string of 5 digits, like `[^0-9]([0-9]{5})[^0-9]`. Then you can capture the inner group (the actual string you want).

Comment: that doesn't work with "12345" as the start of the string and the end of he string are not matched with [^0-9]

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
\D\d{5}\D
```

or maybe

```
\b\d{5}\b
```

I'm not sure how python treats line-endings and whitespace there though.

I believe `^\d{5}$` would not work for you, as you likely want to get numbers that are somewhere within other text.

Comment: the first regex don't work with "12345" and the second one with "12345a"

Answer (score 1):

I use Regex with easier expression :

```
re.findall(r"\d{5}", mystring)
```

It will research 5 numerical digits. But you have to be sure not to have another 5 numerical digits in the string