# what is the way to extract only 2 digits numbers from the sentence using python

Tags: regex, python-3.x, findall

I need to extract only 2 digits numbers from the string using python.
I have tried following things:

```
1. below will extract all the numbers in the sentence.
 age =[int(s) for s in Text .split() if s.isdigit()]

2. Below code will extract only numbers.
age = re.findall(r'\d+', Text )

Text = I am sorry I am able 28 years old I have cough for 3 weeks online company with severe headache the headache is at its cost in the morning and have some people

Actual output : 28,3
Expected output : 28
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Regular Expression Match All 5 Digit Numbers but None Larger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532947/python-regular-expression-match-all-5-digit-numbers-but-none-larger)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regex boundaries `\b`.

**Ex:**

```
import re
Text = "I am sorry I am able 28 years old I have cough for 3 weeks online company with severe headache the headache is at its cost in the morning and have some people"

print(re.findall(r"\b\d{2}\b", Text))
```

**Output:**

```
['28']
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of doing `age = re.findall(r'\d+', Text )` in step 2 try doing `age = re.findall(r'\d\d', Text )`.